# Сertain number counter

Tags: java

How to calculate how many numbers, for example from 1 to 1000, **do not have more than 1 identical digit** (example of a number where more than 1 identical digit: 11, 22, 119, 151, 777)

My try (i made algorithm, but its work when number less 100)

```
public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Number;
        int Number2 =0;
        int ElevenFactor = 0;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("\n Please Enter any Number: ");
        Number = sc.nextInt();
        if (Number>11) {
            ElevenFactor = Number / 11;

        }else{
            ElevenFactor = 0;
        }


        while(Number2 != Number) {
            Number2++;
        }
        System.out.println("\n Answer");
        System.out.println(Number2 - Math.floor(ElevenFactor));
    }
}
```

How do is must work:

input: 30

output: 28

---

input: 99

output: 90

Comment: Create a method to count the occurrences of each digit in a number and then run a loop through the numbers and count numbers which do not have more than 2 occurrences of a digit

Comment: or how to improve the algorithm so that it can count numbers >100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the digits in an array.  So allocate a new array of `int[10]` for each iteration.

When you find a digit `d`, check the array at index `d` to see if it is > 0.  If not, so far so good.  Increment that location and get the next digit.

```java
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      outer:
      for (int numb = 0; numb < 1000; numb++) {
         // initialized to all 0's
         int[] freq = new int[10];// for digits 0 thru 9
         int k = numb;
         while (k > 0) {
            int d = k % 10;
            if (freq[d] > 0) {
               continue outer;
            }
            // update digit count
            freq[d]++;
            k /= 10;
         }
         list.add(numb);
      }
```

The following formats the output

```java
      int count = 0;
      for (int n : list) {
         System.out.printf("%4d ", n);
         if (++count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }
```